# Visio - Add and check connector properties

Tags: graph, visio, weighted

I'm looking for a starting point for a graph project.
I need to create a weighted, directed graph, preferably in Visio.
The graph is composed of shapes and connectors.
I'd like to add a 'weight' attribute to each connector and add a function to check if the weights out of a particular node add to 100.
Any input would be appreciated! :)
-chris